# What is the importance of just in comparative sentence?

Tags: expressions, sentence, expression-choice

Do these two statements mean the same thing?

> 1. Pizza tastes as good as pasta.
> 2. Pizza tastes just as good as pasta.

To me, 1 sounds like pizza tastes at least like pasta or better while 2 sounds like pizza tastes no better than pasta.

Am I right in my interpretation?

Comment: Do dictionaries not give more than the 'just about / barely' sense for 'just'?

Comment: The second one seems to imply that the earlier conversation has been advancing pasta to the detriment of pizza.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your interpretation is not correct. *Just* theoretically tells us pizza does not merely taste about as good as pasta: it tastes *exactly* as good. So it cannot taste slightly less good: it truly is up to the level of goodness of pasta and not an iota lower.

In practice, this mainly serves as a mild intensifier to the expression as a whole; it mostly just adds emphasis.

*Just* doesn't suggest that pizza is better than pasta any more than the variant without *just* does (they may both equally suggest that it is better, or not, depending on context).

Answer (score 0):

**Just as** here means **exactly like**.

**just as** can be used along with adjectives especially when you are using *adjectives of quality*.

> For example, *just as pretty as her.*

So if you intend to say *exactly like pasta* then your interpretation would be correct.